# How to mark or bold or hide some specific date in DateTimePicker Control - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I'm using VB.Net 2019, i need to :

- mark (or bold)
  or
- hide

Some specific date in DateTimePicker control.

Some specific date cannot be
set with MinDate or MaxDate Value, because they are random

Is it possible to do it?

if it's not possible, is there any component that i can use?

i tried to use MonthCalendar,but it is just to big and also it's
difficult while select a range of date with different month

Thank you

Comment: You cannot do this with the WinForms DateTimePicker unless you draw (parts of) it yourself. WPF DatePicker has a blackoutdates property but nothing for winforms

Comment: Thank you,  i'm totally agree with you @CaiusJard. DTP cannot do this unless draw the elements of this control. Is there anyone have any idea about 3rd party control to do this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend third party libraries/software aren't on topic, sorry.. For that ind of research you might get an answer at softwarerecs.stackexchange.com